# Convert a string to a usable json string or array object

Tags: php, arrays, json

A function is taking two arguments as `func($t,$stringt){}`

Where $t is an integer and `$stringt` is any string, the format of `$stringt` is as below

```
for $t = 1;
$stringt = '({A,B,C,D,E,F},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A),(F,A)})'; 
//or it can be
$stringt = '({A,B,C,D,E,F},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(D,A),(B,A),(A,E),(F,A)})';
for $t = 2;
    $stringt = '({A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}),({A,B,C,D,E},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(D,A),(E,D),(A,E),(E,C),(D,B)})';
```

How can I convert this simple string to any usable json string

Say like this

```
 $json = '[

                        [
                             [
                                "A", "B", "C"
                             ],
                             [
                                [
                                    "A" , "B"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "B","C"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "C","A"
                                ]
                             ]
                        ],
                        [
                             [
                                "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
                             ],
                             [
                                [
                                    "A","B"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "B","C"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "C","A"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "D","A"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "E","D"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "A","E"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "E","C"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "D","B"
                                ]
                             ]

                        ] 
        ]';
```

With this I can approach the result required. 
Output I am looking is something like

All combination with element A for second set

```
$array_a = array( array('A','B'),array('C','A'),array('D','A'),array('A','E'));
var_dump($array_a);
echo count($array_a);
```

Similarly for all the value pairs.

Is there any other way to approach with the given input string, say to find all value pare for A(or any other) in the first set and then in second set and in any nth set.

Comment: 1. Get a valid JSON string, 2. Use `json_decode()`. 3. Get an array/object. 4. Do whatever.

Comment: The string can be in that format only .. that is what I am looking to have an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are sure about the format, this worked for me:

```
$json = '({A,B,C,D,E,F},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A),(F,A)})';

$json = preg_replace('/([^\(\)\{\}\[\],]+)/', '"$1"', $json);
$json = preg_replace('/[\{\(]/', '[', $json);
$json = preg_replace('/[\}\)]/', ']', $json);

$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
            [3] => D
            [4] => E
            [5] => F
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => B
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => B
                    [1] => C
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                    [1] => A
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => E
                    [1] => D
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D
                    [1] => A
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => F
                    [1] => A
                )

        )

)
```

It may not work for items that contain any of `[] {} () ,` however.